# When postgres sets "idle_in_transaction"

Tags: postgresql

Can someone explain when Postgres sets status "idle_in_transaction"?

Yes, I know that it set this when the next command does not come from the client and the transaction is idle.
It turns out that after BEGIN idle status is automatically assigned?

Answer (score 0):

It is set when there is an open transaction with no activity. It is something you want to avoid as to holds resources. Potentially the worse the thing is that you do an `UPDATE` that touches many rows and then don't `COMMIT` it. At that point Postgres has to keep both the old and new version of each row around until you either `COMMIT or ROLLBACK`. Because of this `VACUUM` cannot clean up the old rows. This leads to table bloat.

It will be set after BEGIN if no other statements are forthcoming. So:

```
--When I connect.
select datname, pid, state from pg_stat_activity where pid = 15965;
 datname |  pid  | state 
---------+-------+-------
 test    | 15965 | idle
--BEGIN;
select datname, pid, state from pg_stat_activity where pid = 15965;
 datname |  pid  |        state        
---------+-------+---------------------
 test    | 15965 | idle in transaction
--COMMIT; or ROLLBACK;
select datname, pid, state from pg_stat_activity where pid = 15965;
 datname |  pid  | state 
---------+-------+-------
 test    | 15965 | idle
```

Comment: It is worse than that: the open transaction prevents dead row versions from being cleaned up *in any table* (apart from holding locks).

Comment: I meant here a little different:
for example, if a client sends:
begin;
select field1, field2 from test_table;
commit;

Will this code put the idle in transaction status (for a negligible period of time) for example after "begin;"?

Comment: @rs_rs. It is going to depend on the time between begin; and  the select. What the minimum time frame is I don't know. More importantly the statistic collector that records this  is not instantaneous, there is lag in what it records. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  that is not the case, it depends on what is being done in the transaction. e.g. SELECTs won't affect anything(unless a function that changes tables is involved). Second a VACUUM will work on tables that don't have 'in play' rows. I would be interested in an example that locks out all VACUUMs.

Comment: I was too terse. You are right about the `SELECT`s of course, I was thinking of transactions with a transaction ID. Also, dead tuples that are older than the oldest active transaction can be vacuumed. This illustrates what I had in mind: Session 1: `BEGIN; SELECT txid_current();` Session 2: `DELETE FROM atable;` and `VACUUM (VERBOSE) atable;` The `VACUUM` cannot remove any dead tuple.